# Не отображается страница cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Хочу добавить свою измененную страничку корзины.

Для этого я создал дирректорию yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/ и перенес туда файл cart.php из плагина woocommerce.

Так же я удалил страницу корзины отсюда[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если перейти по ссылке mysite/cart я получаю "Oops! That page can’t be found."

Что мне надо сделать, что бы начать отображать ту корзину, которая у меня в теме?

Comment: Нужно создать страницу корзины. Вообще не понятно зачем ее нужно было удалять.

Comment: @noname228 хорошо, я создал пустую страницу, указал ее в выпадающем списке из скрина сверху. Но сообщение то же "Oops! That page can’t be found."

Comment: Я почти уверен, что slug новой страницы не соответствует cart, т.е. нужно либо открыть созданную страницу, либо изменить ее slug

Comment: @noname228 я восстановил старую